# Don't see it : Integration Services Catalog, and open the [All Executions] report

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis, ssms

I have SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2.
I am not seeing the option to the "[All Executions] report" in the Integration Services Catalog . How can I solve it?

[image]

**Update:** I have attached another image that shows that I do not have the same menu as in [the answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/134160/1192) by stacylaray.

[image]

Comment: That's ... curious. Within SSMS, Help, About, what does it report as the version of SSMS that you are using? It has to be 2012+ due to the fact that it knows about the Integration Services Catalogs node in the object explorer. My instinct says permission related but I've not heard of this specific issue before. Try launching SSMS as an administrator (assuming UAC is messing with things). Try verifying you have sufficient permissions (`SELECT TOP 1 * FROM SSISDB.catalog.operations AS O;`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on the SSIS Catalogue, highlight *Reports*, and select *All Executions*.

The Simple Talk article, [SSIS 2012 Projects: Deployment Configurations and Monitoring](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-2012-projects-deployment-configurations-and-monitoring/) by [Feodor Georgiev](https://www.simple-talk.com/author/feodor-georgiev/), includes the following illustration:

> [image: Screenshot]

If you are not observing the *Reports* submenu, try running Setup again and choose *Management Tools* – *Complete*. Try executing SSMS as Administrator.